# The state does not switch after the execution of the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

On my site there is a list of devices with their brief description (made in the form of a table). Information about devices is stored in the firestore.

The user can delete any device, respectively, the device will not be displayed to the user and will be deleted from the database (firestore)

Removing the device is as follows:

1. the user clicks on the delete button;
2. a window opens (something similar to a modal window made using Dialog mui) with a warning about the danger of deletion and two buttons: cancel and confirm;

   2a) when you click on the cancel button, the window closes and you can continue to work
   on the site;

   2b) pressing the confirmation button starts the deletion process, which is accompanied
   by a scroll wheel. After removing the device, the window closes and a notification
   should appear that the operation was completed successfully.

With the appearance of a notification that the operation was completed successfully, I had serious problems.

What am I doing:

1. I created the state `const[notificationShown, setNotificationShown] = useState(false)`;
2. Further I switch this state `setNotificationShown(true)`;
3. And if `notificationShown` it is true, then I display the inscription about the successful removal.

But for some reason, `notificationShown` never switches to true, and accordingly, a record of successful deletion is not displayed.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with `await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams);`
Let me explain: I put `await` before `deleteItem`, since the size of the file that contains information about the device is always different and, accordingly, the deletion time will always be different

```
export function DeleteButton({ item }) {
  const { urlParams } = useContext(PageContext)
  const { firestore } = useContext(AppContext)

  const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);
  const [alertLoading, setAlertLoading] = useState(false);

  // The state that is responsible for notification of successful deletion
  const [notificationShown, setNotificationShown] = useState(false);


  const onNo = () => {
    setAlertShown(false);
  };

  const onYes = async () => {
    setAlertLoading(true);

    try {
      // Removes an entry from the firestore
      await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams);
      
      // Should toggle notificationShown to true and 
      // use setTimeout to hold the notification for two seconds
      setNotificationShown(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNotificationShown(false);
      }, 2000); 

      setAlertShown(false);
    }  finally {
      setAlertLoading(false);
    }
  };

  
  return <ButtonGroup >

            {/* Responsible for the appearance of an inscription about the successful removal */}
            {notificationShown && (<span>The item was removed successfully</span>)} 

            <div onClick={() => setAlertShown(true)}>
                  <DeleteForeverIcon sx={{color: "#ff5141", marginRight: "5px"}}/>
              </div>

            {alertShown && (
                <Dialog open={onYes}>

                    <DialogTitle>Do you want to delete record?</DialogTitle>

                    <DialogContentText>
                       record will be removed from firestore
                    </DialogContentText>

                    {alertLoading 
                        ? <div>
                            <LabledSpinner/>
                          </div>
        
                        : <DialogActions>
                            <Button   onClick={onNo}>Cancel</Button >
                            <Button   onClick={onYes}>Confirm </Button >
                          </DialogActions>}
                     
                                       
                </Dialog>
                )}        
    </ButtonGroup>
}
```

Please help me figure out what could be the reason.

Comment: try do something like   setNotificationShown(!notificationShown);

Comment: @ChamiduPurage Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that the code after `await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams);` even runs? Try adding `console.log('something')` there and see if it prints

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski
 Yes, the code after await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams); performed.
I followed your instructions and the console output is

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue really https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-wood-kfkgre?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I read your question and it's precisely what I did. For me, it looks like your `deleteItem` function throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-3ppnks?file=pages%2Findex.js), your code works for me.

In the demo I added the `notificationShown` state to reflect the current state on the webpage. After clicking confirm and waiting for async, the notification shows, and then removed after 2 seconds.

If the demo doesn't do what you're wanting could you provide some clarification on what the issue(s) are?

Comment: `return` is an operator, it doesn't need parentheses.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Unless you're using the 'return' code on a single line, the interpreter doesn't know where the JSX begins or ends unless you use parentheses.

Comment: It knows where JSX begins and ends because JSX is transpired to one nested object. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-v2pt6o?file=App.tsx)

Comment: Interesting. I've never left a JSX tag on the first line. Using auto-formatting for all my projects it's always put () around my return statement as well. Even official documentation does the parentheses. After reading into it, () is used for formatting and to prevent [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion). Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asynchronous and so `notificationShown` won't update until the next re-render.

`useEffect` allows you to run a code block on a state change and could be what you're after, see below.

```
  const onYes = async () => {
    setAlertLoading(true);

    try {
      // Removes an entry from the firestore
      await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams);
      
      // Should toggle notificationShown to true 
      setNotificationShown(true);

      setAlertShown(false);
    }  finally {
      setAlertLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // use setTimeout to hold the notification for two seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNotificationShown(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, [notificationShown]);
```

More described previous answer, [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately).

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Yes, your explanations seem quite logical, but it still doesn't work. notificationShown does not switch to true. Perhaps you have some other ideas?

Comment: I don't see any other reasons why it wouldn't work. Does the effect hook not do anything on state change?

Comment: Beyond the firestore business, this should somewhat resemble what you're trying to achieve. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-rosalind-ugkl9f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In your example, there is a specific trigger to fire an action. In my case, this is not the case. In my case, you need to wait until the deletion process is completed and then, so that the notification automatically starts

Comment: It should still work the same so long as `setNotificationShown(true)` runs as expected, I don't see why it wouldn't. If you log notificationShown in between the onYes function and the effect hook I imagine it should log both true and false so if it isn't doing that I'm not too sure what else I can provide.

Comment: just notificationShown doesn't switch to true

Answer (score 1):

I think Dialog props is wrong.
Type of open is boolean. Not () => Promise<void>.

```
<Dialog open={alertShown}>

    <DialogTitle>Do you want to delete record?</DialogTitle>

    <DialogContentText>
        record will be removed from firestore
    </DialogContentText>

    {alertLoading 
        ? <div>
            <LabledSpinner/>
          </div>

        : <DialogActions>
            <Button   onClick={onNo}>Cancel</Button >
            <Button   onClick={onYes}>Confirm </Button >
          </DialogActions>}
      
                        
</Dialog>
```

[mui Dialog docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/)

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing that. But that didn't solve the problem